# Webpage is scrollable when i want it to be a fixed size - django

Tags: html, css, django, django-templates

I am working on django template and I am integrating bootstrap into the html tempates for the project. Every template page is scrollable even though the content does not fill the page. I want all the webpages to be unscollable and set the default heigh of the div that contains to the content to be 100 percent of the screen.

I baiscally want to eliminate the scrollablility of the page and set the fixed high to the size of the window that is open.

Can anyone help me. Here is the webpage and the custom css that I added to the bootstrap columns:

```
<div class="col content-max-height">
    {% block content %}
    {% endblock %}
  </div>

{% extends "header.html" %}

{% block content %}
  <h2 class="page-header">{{ group.group.name }}</h2>
  <div class="scrollable-view">
    {% for activity in activities %}
      {% if activity.user == currentUser %}
        {% if activity.general == 2 %}
          <p>{{ activity.description }}</p>
        {% endif %}
      {% endif %}
      {% if activity.user != currentUser %}
        {% if activity.general == 1 %}
          <p>{{ activity.description }}</p>
        {% endif %}
      {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
  </div>
  {% if currentUser == host.user %}
    <a href="{% url 'add_expense' host.group.id %}">Add New Expense</a>
  {% endif %}

{% endblock %}
```

The css that I have added above the bootrap classes is the following...

```
.content-max-height {
  height: 200px !important;
}
```

I added this to make the div in the first part of html code the size of the screen and no bigger to prevent scrolling in the overall webpage.

```
.scrollable-view {
  position: absolute !important;
  width: 100% !important;
  margin-top: 10px !important;
  margin-bottom: 10px !important;
  max-height: 1000px !important;
  overflow-y: scroll !important;
}
```

I want a specific div within the major content div to be a scrollable div if there is content that overflows the overall content div heigh.

Here is the image of the overall screen. you can see the scollable wheel on the side. I want that gone and have the div in the center be scrollable....

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are getting scroll bar that means your body of the HTML has more height than the height of the window.

Here we can do two things :

1. On Body write CSS **overflow:hidden** so that it will not show any content which contributes to increment of the height.
2. In css, update as below. This will not allow the scroll bar to show.

   `.scrollable-view {
     position: absolute !important;
     width: 100% !important;
     margin-top: 10px !important;
     margin-bottom: 10px !important;
     overflow-y: hidden !important;
   }`

Please try this and let me know if its works..     :-)

Comment: If I want to make the div with the menubar fixed in its position. and then have the content below it fill the rest of the screens height. How can I do that so that bot together are 100 percent of the screen... If the screen heigh is 1000px. I want the menubar 100px fixed and the content div 900px fixed in its position.. if the content in the lower div overflows the div height, it becomes scrollable. That is what I want to acheive. what kind of css do I need to add to make that happen or what bootstrap classes allow me to do that... @Sunokumar

Comment: when I start messing with the position css all the columns and rows in the container get completely changed and make really weird changes to the css and layout before the changes were added.

Comment: I think this is what you want. Below is the link of jsfiddle.    
                   https://jsfiddle.net/L1wdv25e/1/   check this out.

Comment: So i looked at the fiddle and it works in the fiddle. I then copied and pasted what you have into one of the django templates that i dont user just to see if it gives the same result. it does not give the same results. the mavbar does not stay fixed to the top...

Comment: I also dont see any of the linkes that are in the nav bar.... like home and links all is see is brand in the header

Comment: are you including bootstrap.css file anywhere in your template file?? I suspect you have not added bootstrap css file.  Can you show me your header.html?

Comment: Copy and paste this in the head section of the header.html file.                  
`<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">`

Comment: Cool Enjoy!! Try reading django documentation properly, its very nice.